# Mr and Mrs Zimmerman want to give their baby a first name and a second name so that the baby's three initials are in alphabetical order.

Tags: permutations, combinations

Mr and Mrs Zimmerman want to give their baby a first name and a second name so that the baby's three initials are in alphabetical order. How many different initials could this baby end up with eg. B,G,Z is acceptable but G,B,Z and B,B,Z are not acceptable.

Comment: Hint:  There are $\frac {25\times 24}{2}$ ways to choose unordered pairs of two letters (neither of them $Z$).  Given such a pair there is exactly one way to put it in alphabetical order.

Comment: Robert Allen Zimmerman. Doh' that doesn't work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can think of this question in two steps:

- First, choose the two letters for first name and middle name
- Second, put the two letters in order

There are ${25\choose 2}$ ways to choose the two letters, and there's only one way to put the two letters in the correct order.

Therefore in total, there are ${25\choose 2}=300$ initials could the baby end up with.

Hope that helps!